# Field formatter to display base 64 data image

Tags: 8, entities

When I use `echo $src` I get the following result:

> data:image/svg+xml;base64,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

If I print `$src` inside `<img>` tags, the image is not rendering properly: *data:* is automatically cut off from the URL.

```
<img src="image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```

This is the field formatter I am using.

```
class ImageDefaultFormatter extends FormatterBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = array();
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      if (isset($item->value)) {
        $src = $item->value;
        $elements[$delta] = array('#markup' => '<img src="'.$src.'">');
      }
    }
    return $elements;
  }
}
```

Comment: for time being I did it through javascript. I print the $src in a wrapper div and then used jQuery to create image using printed $src data. Not able to figure out whats wrong by printing image using php.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

$src = $item->value;
$image = new FormattableMarkup('<img src=":src"/>', [':src' => $src]);
$elements[$delta] = [
  '#markup' => $image,
];
```

Comment: or 
            [
              '#markup' => Markup::create('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $data . '"/>')
            ]

Answer (score 2):

```
$form['base64_image'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => "<img width='100px' height='100px' src='{{ data }}' />",
  '#context' => [
    'data' => $base64_image_data,
  ],
];
```